# How do I display on Tkinter images from the web without saving them on

Tags: python, tkinter

first let me say that I have searched for this and while there may seem to be duplicates, they mostly use libs that don't work on python 3 or have been deprecated.

So I'm trying to use this code to display an image on tkinter which I don't want to save the image in a file on my computer. Here is the code I'm using:

```
r =  requests.get(url, stream = True)
b64_data = base64.encodestring(r.raw)
root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data= b64_data)

panel = Label(root, image = img)

panel.pack(side= "bottom", fill = "both", expand= "yes")

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error message I am getting

> TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not HTTPResponse

so my guess is that I have to convert into another format in order to run the image through the encodestring function but I don't really know what to do. I am also guessing that the PhotoImage thing will only work if the data is in gif format, which mine isn't mine is jpg. So I think maybe the best way is to create a temporary file or something and then  get rid of it after I've used it but I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: Try `PhotoImage(data=r.content)`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann tried that and I get the same error

Comment: For what code line?

Comment: ohh woops that was the wrong line, it works now, Thanks a lot!